# check DOM element exist in js / angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs

http://plnkr.co/edit/LZUa1tm7EROk8zcw6sGh?p=preview

```
angular.module('myModule', [])
  .controller('myDirective', function() {
    console.log(angular.element('.myClass').prop('offsetWidth'));
  });
```

I want to check where the DOM is visible or not in angularjs. But got an error of myClass is not a function?

Comment: Can you show an console output of the problem?

Comment: Your controller name in myDirective and you have set ng-controller as myClass

Answer (score 1):

Change your controller name `myDirective` to `myClass`.

Try like this

```
angular.module('myModule', [])
  .controller('myClass', function($scope) {
    var mClass = document.getElementsByClassName("myClass");
    console.log(angular.element(mClass).prop('offsetWidth'));

  });
```

<kbd>**[`DEMO`](http://plnkr.co/edit/cB6hI698FXMnnt5biADT?p=preview)**</kbd>

**N:B**: DOM related task should be handled in the directive instead of controller.

Answer (score 0):

Angular.element is different from document.getElementsByClassName. angular.element takes in an element, for eg-

```
var elem = angular.element('<div class="myDiv">{{ model.input }}</div>')
```

The above one is correct, but lets see the wrong version too

```
var elem = angular.element('.myDiv')
```

This one wont work

For your case do it like this :-

angular.element($document.find('div.myClass'))

Note :- you will have to inject $document in the controller, this way you can keep your whole code in angular format instead of using proper javascript methods like  document.getElementsByClassName()

Hope it helps